# Array will not fill backwards in C++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to fill an array backwards from 20 to 0 but whenever I print it out it still prints out forwards. For instance I want to put in 1,2,3,4,5 and have it come out as 5,4,3,2,1.

I have attempted to do a for loop that counts backwards from 20 to 0 but when i print it it is still coming out incorrect. Any help?

```
int temp;
for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--)
{
    cout << "Please enter the next number. Use a -1 to indicate you are done: ";
    cin >> temp;
    while(temp > 9 || temp < -2)
    {
        cout << "You may only put numbers in 0 - 9 or -1 to exit. Please enter another number: ";
        cin >> temp;
    }
    arr1[i] = temp;
    cout << arr1[i];
}
for (int i = 21; i > 0; i--)
{
    cout << arr1[i];
```

Comment: You're printing it backwards.

Comment: How big is arr1? 20, 21 or 22? And why are you leaving [0] out?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i  < 20; ++i) { cout << arr1[i]; }`

Comment: `int i = 21;` is not the same as `int i = 20;`.  How big is your array.  You really should have an [mcve]

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

What's the size of your array?
**Assume that the size is 21 (indexes from 0 to 20).**

First of all please note that your first loop will never populate the array at index 0 (something like this `arr1[0] = temp` will never be executed inside your first loop).
If you want to avoid this behavior you should write your first for loop like this:

`for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--){`...`}`.

The second for loop has some issues:

1. You are traversing the array backwards while you want to do the opposite.
2. The loop starts from an index out of bound (21).
3. The loop may print some undefined values (You should remember the index of the last added value).

I suggest you to use other data structures like a Stack but if you want to use an array you can edit your code as follows:

```
int i;
for (i = 20; i >= 0; i--){...}
for (i; i <= 20; ++i) { cout << arr1[i]; }
```

If you don't want to declare `int i;` outside of the loop you can do something like that:

```
int lastAdded;
for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--){
    ...
    lastAdded = i;
}
for (int i = lastAdded; i <= 20; i++) { cout << arr1[i]; }
```

Edit: Note that neither your code nor mine stops asking for a new value after the insertion of a -1.
If you want to achieve this behavior you should use a while loop instead of the first for loop and check for the exit condition.

Comment: He doesn't check the exit condition from the first loop either.

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you! I've added a note about it.